# Getting the attribute of the element that has the mouse over

Tags: jquery, hover, selection, mouseover, attr

I'm trying to make a legend system to my web site.. It's a simple task...
When the mouse is over the elements, jquery gets the `value` attribute and adds this value to a `div` below...

I don't know how to get the attribute, because the selection return 3 elements...
Here is the code..

```
$(function(){
$('#legends .item')
    .mouseover(function(){
            $('#legend-tags').html($('#tag-video').attr("value")).fadeIn();
        })
    .mouseout(function(){   
            $('#legend-tags').fadeOut();
        });
});
```

This selection returns 3 elements, and I want to get the attribute of the element that has the mouse over in the moment. In this test code, I'm getting the attribute of the `#tag-video`, that is one of the elements.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="legends">
  <span>TAGS</span>
  <div id="tag-motion" class="item tag-motion" value="motion"></div>
  <div id="tag-design" class="item tag-design" value="design"></div>
  <div id="tag-video" class="item tag-video" value="video"></div>
  <div id="legend-tags">legend</div>                
</div>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
#legends .item
{
    display: block;
    width: 27px;
    height: 27px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-bottom: 5px;    
}

#legend-tags
{
    display: none;
}

.tag-video
{
    background-image: url('../img/tag-video.svg');
}

.tag-video:hover
{
    background-image: url('../img/tag-video-over.svg');
}

.tag-design
{
    background-image: url('../img/tag-design.svg');
}

.tag-design:hover
{
    background-image: url('../img/tag-design-over.svg');
}

.tag-motion
{
    background-image: url('../img/tag-motion.svg');
}

.tag-motion:hover
{
    background-image: url('../img/tag-motion-over.svg');
}
```

Comment: you also have a misspelling in javascript and css, item vs iten

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use

```
$('#legend-tags').html($(this).attr("value")).fadeIn();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LjktG/)

In your case you had hard coded `$('#tag-video')` instead of that you need to get the element over which mouse is hovered, this element is available in the hover callback as `this` variable.

Note: There is a type in your selector `$('#legends .iten')` it should be `$('#legends .item')`

Comment: I thought that in this case the callback would refer to #legend-tags not to the selection... where I can learn more about that?

Comment: when the mouse pass over the tree items fast the animation keeps running after I put the mouse out, I tried to put an .stop(), but than the element never fades in or out completely...

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

```
$("div.item").hover(function(){
    $('#legend-tags').html( $(this).attr("value") ).fadeIn();
});
```